# Drupal Content Manager module that approve content, tracks changes

Tags: drupal, content-management

I know for a fact that Drupal is a content management software. What I would like to know is, is their any module in drupal that does content management? Like approving a submitted contents, post or comments, Track changes and so on and so forth. If you visit this site http://www.formstack.com/forms/envato-tuts__net__content_submission the page contains fields for content submission, I'm pretty sure that they have some sort of management tool that an editor can then edit the submitted article, approve it or deny it. Do you know some sort of wordpress plugin or drupal module that does the same?

Your opinion is greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the [Workflow](https://www.drupal.org/project/workflow) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... allows you to create arbitrary Workflows, and assign them to Entities.
>
> Workflows are made up of workflow states. Transitions between states can be allowed per role. For example, a workflow with the states Draft, Review, and Published could be assigned to the Story node type. Only users with role 'chief editor' can set Stories to the published state. You can set up the Workflow to alter states from form, page, comment and a special workflow tab.
>
> Transitions between workflow states can have actions assigned to them. In our example, we could assign an action so that when the story moves from the Draft state to the Review state an email is sent out. Another action could be assigned to the transition from Review to Published so that the node's status is set to Published (and becomes visible on your website).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) and/or [Revisioning](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning).